# At which memory segment does pointer c+9 point for given function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

1. `void f() {int *c=(int*)malloc(10);}`
2. `void f() {int c[10];}`

I think that on in first case `c+9` will be pointing at element `c[9]` in array that is allocated on heap.

And for the second case I think that `c+9` will be pointing at the same element `c[9]` of the array that is located on stack.

I am new to programming and I am not sure if it is correct answer. thanks for any help.

Comment: The first case is all wrong. The argument for calls to `malloc()` should be the number of bytes required. You're creating storage for `int` variables here, so you only reserved enough space for two 32-bit ints or one 64-bit int. Try `int *c=malloc(10 * sizeof(int));` instead.

Comment: Perhaps re-read (or read) the manual page for malloc would be a good idea

Comment: I double checked it, it was from test on programming at college so I cant change size that is allocated. and how can i check if my answer is correct?

Comment: You're on the right track but the professor appears to have made a mistake In his code. The point is that unless the allocated size is adequate, `c+9` will be invalid in case 1 and won't point anywhere that is defined. You should seek clarification.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because the error is not the OP's but a professor's, who should have known better, unless it's a trick question.

Comment: I am pretty sure it was a trick question, but I still dont understand why would someone downvote if I did a mistake, if I knew evrything i would not be asking here. and thank you for helping me.

Comment: I think there are *two* trick questions here. Be warned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases the behaviour is undefined. In case 1 it points beyond the allocated piece of memory. In case two it points into an array which was allocated on the stack and which has now been popped.